Receiving Destination Folder Access Denied error on new file server even though group has all necessary permissions
Recently set up a new file server to replace an old one. I copied all of the old files and permissions from the last file server using a script and everything seems correct just looking at it. However, I am unable to edit or modify anything on the server when using a user account. Even if I go into an excel sheet in a random subfolder and edit it, I can't save over it. I checked all file permissions and group permissions, and the group I'm using has Modify and Edit permissions. The server itself is not set to read only. I don't know what could be causing the issue. I can edit things perfectly fine when using an admin account, but when using a user account in a group with correct permissions, I run into the issue. I changed ownership from system to my admin group but that didn't really affect anything because the issue affects users and groups. Has anyone run into this problem and does anyone have a solution? Thank you.

the group I'm using has Modify and Edit permissions What group? An AD group? A local group?

Yes sorry, an AD group used for access to the file server. Locally, everything works. The issue is when using shared access from user accounts. Should have specified that.

What are the share permissions? (Not the file permissions).

The share permissions were set to Read Only! Thank you for the help, the problem is solved!
